# Added layouts folder but not appear in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-put-android-layout-files-in-subfolders-1f7cf07ff48f). However, the layouts folder does not appear in my Android Studio although I have specified it with it's subfolders in gradle:

[image]

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layouts/..',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/..',
                            'src/main/res/layouts',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are spelling them wrong, It should be `layout` and not `layouts`. If your doing subfolders your parent sub folder need to have layout folder and you need to place all your xml in them.

Comment: That tutorial shows can use `layouts`. My purpose is to subfolders my layout folder.

Comment: Got it! I thought in AS it is going to appear as subfolderised as in the Finder/Windows Explorer, but actually not. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Rendy check this article if you want more info https://proandroiddev.com/split-layout-into-subfolder-in-android-5bf76f805e90